# vte background image workaround

Tags: c, gtk3, vte

I'm using libvte-2.91 in debian stretch for my terminal application written in c using gtk3.  Now that they have removed the direct ability to apply a background image to the terminal, what creative workarounds have been devised for accomplishing this goal?